# Disable code folding in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

How can I disable (or hide) this part in IntelliJ idea ?

[image]

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-folding-2.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Go to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding**

Uncheck **Show code folding outline**.

[image]

Comment: This removes the outline, but how do I stop Intellij folding the code completely? I unchecked all the boxes in that settings menu and still code is folded - the imports, for instance

Comment: I have the same issue with IntelliJ 2017.2, it's a bug

Comment: In IntelliJ 2018 one has to uncheck all boxes bellow the label Collapse by default.

Comment: Still having this problem in 2018.2. I unchecked all the boxes, but the region blocks are still being folded automatically.

Comment: @Adam stopping it completely is found in the same settings.

Answer (score 10):

For IntelliJ 15+ with default keyboard bindings

Press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on a mac or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on windows, to search for an action, and type **code folding**. This pops up a menu with an option of 'Show code folding outline' and on the right of it is an off/on switch. You can change this with <kbd>enter</kbd> or just click on it.

The settings dialog is old-hat these days.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 2016.2. I press `ctrl+shift+A` and type, but the characters go into the code editor window.

Comment: Your key-bindings might be different, so YMMV on that. You can examine the bindings and see what 'Find Action By Name' is bound to on the mapping set you use. It's ctrl-shift-A on windows by default, and I seem to recall that its cmd-shift-a on the default osx settings, but there are two sets of osx settings, and others besides so you might be using something different.

Comment: Thanks! Super easy. It shows a toggle bar to turn off code folding. Worked with only 3 steps in 14.1.7! (compared to all the menu options)

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what OP is asking, if one wishes to just hide the folding outline, then the  [@Phiter answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34552107/410624) is correct.

However if one wishes to disable the actual code folding just uncheck boxes below the label Collapse by default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

BEFORE:

[image]

AFTER:

[image]

To disable the folding icons and folding completely uncheck all checkboxes as depicted here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Color

If you want to be able to fold code without seeing the ugly Tear Line then set...

`Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Tear line` to same as

`Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Gutter background`

Then

`Editor > Color Scheme > General > Editor > Tear selection` to a different color

This should make it invisible, but still accessible when needed.

#### Code folding settings

These can be found here.

`File > Settings > Editor > General > Code Folding`

These settings should be enough to get the look and functionality you want. I personally like it to be invisible but I like to fold some `HTML` every now and then, but never folded by default. Jetbrains, of course, have a setting for that which you can find with the paths above.

Answer (score 0):

1. File > Settings > Keymap
2. Find Hot Keys (comment)
3. Add new combination Hot Key for comment

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqFSa.png)